# Is there a way to use dotnet command to determine the version number of the project build?

Tags: asp.net, github-actions, dotnet-cli

How can I retrieve the version number of a dotnet project using a GitHub Actions? If I can determine the version using a command line, I can execute that same command within the GitHub workflow and store the result in a variable. For instance, if my project contains the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<VersionPrefix>3.0.0</VersionPrefix>
<VersionSuffix>beta</VersionSuffix>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I want to output `3.0.0-beta` as the version number.

##### UPDATED

After feedback from @Lex Li, I added the following conditional check

```
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>3.0.0</VersionPrefix>
    <VersionSuffix>beta</VersionSuffix>
    <VersionSuffix Condition="'$(VersionSuffix)'!='' AND '$(BuildNumber)' != ''">$(VersionSuffix)-$(BuildNumber)</VersionSuffix>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="MyCustomTarget">
    <Message Text="$(VersionPrefix)-$(VersionSuffix)" Importance="High" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="MyCustomTarget" Condition="'$(VersionSuffix)'!='' AND '$(BuildNumber)' != ''">
    <Message Text="$(VersionPrefix)-$(VersionSuffix)" Importance="High" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

The condition check gives me the following error

```
error MSB4057: The target "MyCustomTarget" does not exist in the project.
```

If I remove the `Condition="'$(VersionSuffix)'!='' AND '$(BuildNumber)' != ''"` from the second target, I get `3.0.0-beta` as expected.

Comment: Your edits belong to a totally different question, on how to properly set and handle conditions. Be fair and ask a new question please.

Answer (score 1):

A few simple steps.

## Define a custom target

1. Add a `Directory.Build.props` file to your project folder, so it will be automatically imported by MSBuild.
2. Use the following contents to add a custom target to print out the full version string you wanted.

```xml
<Project>
    <Target Name="MyCustomTarget">
        <Message Text="$(VersionPrefix)-$(VersionSuffix)" Importance="High" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

## Call this target

Now at command prompt you can run the following

```bash
$ dotnet msbuild /t:MyCustomTarget /nologo
3.0.0-beta
```

`/nologo` is needed to suppress the standard MSBuild output like "MSbuild version ... for .NET".

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It got me closer to what I want. When trying to add a condition check to override the first target, I get an error `error MSB4057: The target "MyCustomTarget" does not exist in the project.` Please check my updated question for more details on what I had done.